# Python `type(x)==` what?

Tags: python, class, types

In a code, I am trying to check the type of a class of a variable entered into a function.  What I want is something like this:

```
def foo(x):
    if type(x)=='int':
       pass
```

But I can't find anything that I can put in place of `'int'` that will return `True` when I input an integer.  I have made a temporary fix by doing `type(x)==type(1)`, but I would like to know what to do to not use this sneaky trick.

Comment: If you find yourself needing to explicitly check the type, the design is probably bad. What's the bigger context here?

Comment: Doing this sort of thing is discouraged and considered poor form

Comment: @Daenyth I am making an imaginary number class and trying to define multiplication both with other imaginary numbers and with integers.

Comment: @PygameNerd Python has complex numbers built-in. `>>> 1+1j` -> `(1+1j)`

Comment: @JAB I had no idea.  Still nice to know the answer to my question though.

Comment: @PygameNerd you should find all the complex math functions you need in [`cmath`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html)

Comment: looking forward to single dispatch http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/#user-api

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `int` and [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(x, int):
```

You *could* restrict yourself to *just* the type with:

```
if type(x) is int:
```

but that excludes subclasses of `int`.

However, ask yourself why you are testing for specific types; better to duck-type, and ask for forgiveness.